# Delphi EDataBaseError - Operation Not Supported. How can I solve it?

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress

I'm trying to query data from MySQL5 db, but when I use some other features from SQL code, I have the following error returned: [0x0005]: Operation Not Supported.

My SQL code query:

```
Select 
  s.nome, s.id_sistema, s.st_sis 
from 
  perm_usuar as p 
inner join 
  sistemas as s 
on 
  s.id_sistema = p.id_sistema 
where 
  p.id_usuario = "' + idusuario + '"'
```

When I don't use those features, it works just as well:

```
Select 
  sistemas.nome, sistemas.id_sistema, sistemas.st_sis 
from 
  perm_usuar 
inner join 
  sistemas 
on 
  sistemas.id_sistema = perm_usuar.id_sistema 
where 
  perm_usuar.id_usuario = "' + idusuario + '"'
```

Also, if I try to use WHERE of a joined table, I get the same error... I'm using DBExpress on Delphi XE8, with the following components: SQLConnection, SQLDataSet and SQLQuery.

When I use the code directly on MySQL, it works fine.

Why is it being returned and what's the solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for sharing your story. What is your question?

Comment: You don't need the `as` before the table alias. Also, *stop concatenating your SQL* and learn to use parameterized queries. It makes the code much cleaner, it allows queries to execute more quickly because they can be cached after compilation, and it protects you against SQL injection. It also avoids having difficulties with data type conversions and proper quoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution! The problem were on SQLQuery1.RecordCount. By what I read, the dbExpress is unidirectional, so the RecordCount bring it resource, however have its limitations (you can see here: http://edn.embarcadero.com/ru/article/28494)

Before (returning error):

```
 SQL1.SQL.Clear;
 SQL1.SQL.Add(CodigoMYSQL);
 SQL1.Open;
 SQL1.First;
 cont := SQL1.RecordCount; //have limitations
 if cont > 0 then // check
  begin
   for i := 1 to cont do //loop in
    begin
     for ii := 0 to NValue do
      result[ii].Add(SQL1.Fields[ii].AsString);
     SQL1.Next;
    end;
  end;
 SQL1.Close;
```

** SQL1 = SQLQuery1

After (solved):

```
 SQL1.SQL.Clear;
 SQL1.SQL.Add(CodigoMYSQL);
 SQL1.Open;
 SQL1.First;
 if not SQL1.IsEmpty then //check
  begin
    ii := 0;
    while not SQL1.Eof do //till the end
    begin
     for ii := 0 to NValue do
      result[ii].Add(SQL1.Fields[ii].AsString);
     SQL1.Next;
     inc(ii);
    end;
  end;
 SQL1.Close;
```

Now I can use even more complex one SQL codes and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the status report. I'm assuming that you intended to *ask* a question, e.g.

***Q:*** Why is this error being returned?

As far as why you are seeing that behavior, my suspicion is that the issue is with the **`AS`** keyword.  (That's just a guess.)

Some databases, such as Oracle, disallow the `AS` keyword in the assignment of a table alias, following the ANSI SQL standards. Other databases don't follow the standard as closely and (as an extension) allow (but don't require) the `AS` keyword.

The database interface/driver components you're using may be designed to support "universal" syntax. The interface library may be rejecting the SQL statement because of the non-standard `AS` keyword.

***Q:*** How do I fix this?

You could try removing the unnecessary `AS` keywords.

If that doesn't change the behavior, then maybe the database interface library doesn't support table aliases. (That would be bizarre.)

If that doesn't resolve the issue, you may consider switching to a different database interface/driver, one that is specific to MySQL.

Comment: I just gave an example. What I'm saying is that I have some features, like this one that don't work... I'm not able to try your suggestion now. As soon I can I will.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong, I tried to do a question.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with a "database independent" interface. I think the behavior you are observing is intentional. It's "by design". I think the goal of the interface is to "work" with several different databases, e.g.  SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc. And a simplistic approach to implementing that would be to accept only the "lowest common denominator" SQL. That is, accept only SQL syntax that would be supported by *all* of those databases. (That's really just a guess.)

Comment: @user3175774: The post doesn't appear to be any actual *question*. Were you asking *why* some features of MySQL are not supported? Were you asking what features are supported?  Were you asking if you should be using a different database driver?  Or if you should be using something other than Delphi? (We don't see a *question* being asked. What we see is a status report.) Please see:  [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I edited the post. About what you said, I think it makes sense. What I'll try is to use other SQL syntax from other DataBase (and search for docs). When I try I'll be in touch with you.

Comment: I haven't found much on docs... Another feature that gets the same error is when I use WHERE on JOINED columns. That's a very important one feature, so I get limited on my queries.

Comment: I'm almost sure I found the problem. I should have passed more details. What I think is the problem, is the following line `cont := SQLQuery1.RecordCount;` But I can't use just isEmpty(), cause I need to count how many items I have to loop in.